# \newcolumntype doesn't emit any warning for the redefinition of a primitive type of column

Tags: arrays

With the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{c}{l}
$\begin{array}{cc}
a+b+c & a \\
d & e 
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

I expect a warning for the redefinition of the primitive type of column `c`.

Indeed, in `array.sty` (version 2.4k 2018-12-30) we have at the ligne 241 some code which deals with such a warning.

```
\def\newcolumntype#1{%
  \edef\NC@char{\string#1}%
  \@ifundefined{NC@find@\NC@char}%
    {\@tfor\next:=<>clrmbp@!|\do{\if\noexpand\next\NC@char
        \PackageWarning{array}%
                       {Redefining primitive column \NC@char}\fi}%
     \NC@list\expandafter{\the\NC@list\NC@do#1}}%
    {\PackageWarning{array}{Column \NC@char\space is already defined}}%
```

The `\noexpand` at the fourth line seems strange to me.

Comment: The bug tracker is here: https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues

Comment: Right. I will report a bug.

Comment: Thank you very much for your recent edit for my old answer.

Answer (score 4):

It was originally

```
\if\next\NC@char
```

but it was changed to

```
\if\noexpand\next\NC@char
```

I think the intended change was

```
\if\expandafter\noexpand\next\NC@char
```

to guard against `array` package being loaded after `!` had been made active in some language setups.

the change is wrong but was done in March 1994 and no one reported it before....